# When is the filter value available to a context filter in a view?

Tags: 7, views, uri

There is very odd negative grammer for setting up Context filters in views.

I set a context filter to take a value from the URL (perhaps context filters are primarily for something else?)

However when I go to set it up I need to put my details into the field labelled

```
WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS NOT AVAILABLE
```

This seems very odd to me, could someone explain to me When the filter is available?

I may not be making any sense but then again neither does that page!

Comment: When you talk about "that page", it would be nice to provide a link. Now we don't know what steps you followed, so we can't know what's wrong and where your problems came from. Alternatively, write step by step what you did, what you expected and what you got, without any references to external site. That would be preferable, actually.

Comment: Hi Molot, Thank you for your comment.  I'm just adding a context filter to a plain view on the core view creation page.  My question has been answered below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the very top of the contextual filter configuration window you have:

> This display does not have a source for contextual filters, so no
>   contextual filter value will be available unless you select 'Provide
>   default'.

The answer to your question `When the filter is available?` is short:

**The filter is available only if has been provided.**

Let say, you want to show a block with the content that depend on node id. Obviously you don't want to provide the node id by yourself on each node to see what the block content is. You don't need to provide it, because the node id is in the URL, so **it's available**. Of course the node id is not always in the URL, for example if you're viewing a user profile or a list of recently added articles. That's why this fieldset has been labeled:

**WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS NOT AVAILABLE**

In this fieldset you can decide what to do when the filter hasn't been provided (display all results? provide default? .. many options there..)

Comment: Thanks.  I see I was assuming that the source in the first instance is the URL but I see it is not.  Now it makes more sense.   Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Good one Toby,
As I understand it;

A contextual filter source can be anything; like if i have to embed a views from my code to output the result; I'd feed the contextual parameters as last param in `views_embed_view();`

Hence, The views page makes a little sense with the sentence `'WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS NOT AVAILABLE'`, where you supply the secondary source of a contextual param.